# DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS in MariaDB - syntax error

Tags: sql, mariadb

Can someone explain me, what's wrong with my SQL query?

```
ALTER TABLE tableName DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS columnName;
```

MariaDB gives me this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax 
to use near 'IF EXISTS columnName' at line 1
```

A tried a lot of syntax modification, but without positive result.

Comment: `drop column if exists` isn't valid MySQL syntax, so I'd be surprised if it were supported in MariaDB.

Comment: in MariaDB documentations (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/alter-table/#drop-column-if-exists-col_name-cascaderestrict) you can find this statement.

Comment: The syntax was introduced in MariaDB **10.0**. You must be using 5.5.

Comment: From changelog:  "----- 2013-04-24 MariaDB 10.0.2 -- -- ----- MDEV-318 IF (NOT) EXIST clauses for ALTER TABLE (MWL #252). Syntax modified to allow statements: ALTER TABLE ADD/DROP COLUMN ALTER TABLE ADD/DROP INDEX ALTER TABLE ADD/DROP FOREIGN KEY ALTER TABLE ADD/DROP PARTITION ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN ALTER TABLE MODIFY COLUMN DROP INDEX to have IF (NOT) EXISTS options. Appropriate implementations added to mysql_alter_table(). "

Comment: Thank you guys, I am using 5.5 version so this syntax is not supported.

Answer (score 3):

I tested it on dbfiddle.uk (MariaDB 10.2 RC) and it works.  Are you sure about your MariaDB version (`SELECT VERSION();`)  and the presence of the command in that version? (I suppose it doesn't support until MARIADB 10)

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (ID INT, DESCR VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1, 'Test');
SELECT * FROM T1;
ALTER TABLE T1 DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS XXX; /* no error */
SELECT * FROM T1;
ALTER TABLE T1 DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS DESCR; /* column dropped*/
SELECT * FROM T1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did today `ALTER TABLE table_name DROP IF EXISTS column_name;` and it works :P

MariaDB 10.0

Comment: This does not look like a full answer. You can leave a comment for things like this.

Comment: Works like it should

Answer (score -2):

For newer versions:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name;
```